# Add data to firestore with User ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a webb app for adding data to firestore, I can add with the code below but I want to use the user id which user signed in, I have the "uid"

```
//saving data
$('#form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = $('[name = name]').val();
  let cityLAT = $('[name = cityLAT]').val();
  let cityLONG = $('[name = cityLONG]').val();
  db.collection('campaigns').add({
    name: name,
    cityLAT: cityLAT,
    cityLONG: cityLONG
  });
  $('[name = name]').val('');
  $('[name = cityLAT]').val('');
  $('[name = cityLONG]').val('');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you're asking, but it sounds like you don't want to use the automatically generated document ID provided by `add()`.  If you want to use your own document ID, simply build a reference to that document, and call `set()` on it.

```
const ref = db.collection('campaigns').doc(uid);  // whatever ID you want here
ref.set({ ... });  // whatever fields you want here.
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. You are right I dont want to use the auto generated uid, now I am using the signed users id ok.. but when I add a new item it over writes the old one how can I add multiple datas with same uid.

Comment: Since you have a new problem now, could you post a new question here on Stack Overflow that describes the new problem, what you've tried to solve it, and how it doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Ok I am going to add a new one.